# Free server solution for strict content photos with geotags

Tags: geocoding, flickr, geotagging, panoramio

I would like to create some kind of open free "group" posting of photos with geotags

First I thought about [Panoramio](http://www.panoramio.com/), but seems there is no API for photos upload.

By now I can see only two ways:

- [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) - there are groups but you have to approve group membership anyway, or use tags for grouping which is bad for maintenance
- Custom server solution which will cost efforts and hosting

Can you suggest other free photo services with geotags functionality, or opensource solutions?

Thank you!

**EDIT**
:) Want to add, that I am intrasted in services with **open API** that is why I thought its a good idea ask this question at SO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, Picasa may be an alternative in some way.
[Picasa access in android: PicasaUploadActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193700/picasa-access-in-android-picasauploadactivity/2880776#2880776)

Answer (score 0):

it also seems like panoramio does have an API based on services with responses in JSON

the request will be something like

```
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?order=popularity&set=public&from=0&to=10&minx=-124.29382324218749&miny=36.089060460282006&maxx=-119.8773193359375&maxy=38.724090458956965&callback=MyCallback
```

checkout [this post](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2008/06/panoramio-api-markermanager-instant.html) in google geo developers blog for more info

hope it helps.

G.

Comment: Yes, Panoramio has it's api http://www.panoramio.com/api/widget/api.html but as I stated in question, it has "no API for photos upload"... I need a way to upload photos from my code. But thank you anyway!