# How to access a fixed user's data via Picasa API in android

Tags: android, picasa, google-api-java-client

I am writing an android application, which will access a user (functional account)'s photos.
If possible even hard coding the functional account id& password would be fine. No end-user interaction is required.

**Not able to use the google data api as android don't support** 
So the closest thing I found is this Single-user "installed" client authentication
in [Gdata API doc](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#ClientLogin),
To use ClientLogin (also called "Authentication for Installed Applications"), create a PicasawebService object, then invoke the setUserCredentials method to set the user ID and password

```
PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1"); 
myService.setUserCredentials("liz@gmail.com", "mypassword");
```

**Picasa Service is Not available in the API console.**

Meanwhile, when I try to use the OAuth 2.0 it is not availalbe

I wonder Picasa should be quite popular, what is the best way to do such simple access?

**official picasa-atom-oauth sample**

[This](https://code.google.com/searchframe#ZgtES37yEeo/picasa-atom-oauth-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/picasa/model/Auth.java&q=picasa%20package:google-api-java-client%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=8&sq=) is the official picasa-atom-oauth sample I found. There is a customized call-back server class, however seems it is making use of the browser to get the token. Is it possible to hard code the password in it?

I read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193700/picasa-access-in-android-picasauploadactivity), and seems there is also issue on the token.
Did anyone succeed to use `"oauth2:https://picasaweb.google.com/data/"` as suggested?

Comment: share some code it is very usefull to me. Iam not found `google api client 1.10.1_beta` give me the link. we have any example share to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after googling more examples, the old client login is the way to go.

I used google api client 1.10.1-beta

```
  private static String getTokenByAuthenticatingWithClientLogin(HttpTransport transport) throws IOException {
    ClientLogin authenticator = new ClientLogin();
    authenticator.authTokenType = "lh2";
    authenticator.username = "username";
    authenticator.password = "password";
    authenticator.transport = transport;
    return authenticator.authenticate().getAuthorizationHeaderValue();
  }
```

set the token in headers

```
GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
headers.setApplicationName("APOD/1.0");
headers.setGDataVersion("2");
  String token = getTokenByAuthenticatingWithClientLogin(transport);
  headers.setAuthorization(token);
```

Then use com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory to construct the request.